# install of node-red-contrib-i2c fails with NPM

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, node-red

I have been having problems with my node red installation and the install of additional node packages...I am trying to install the node-red-contrib-i2c package on Raspberry PI http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-i2c ...this is my console output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm install node-red-contrib-i2c
```

more console output...then error:

```
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-i2c/node_modules/i2c/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-i2c/node_modules/i2c
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! i2c@0.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the i2c@0.2.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the i2c package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls i2c
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-red-contrib-i2c"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Something similar happens with several other packages that I have also tried to install including the MCP3008 ADC node package.

Comment: Did you read the document pointed to in the warning? `/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian`

Comment: It didn't shed much light on the subject or I didn't understand how it applies.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `$HOME/.node-gyp`.
It should fix your problem

Comment: So I don't believe that I have this...is it a directory? 

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rm .node-gyp
rm: cannot remove ‘.node-gyp’: No such file or directory

Comment: Try on root account

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ended up solving the problem. What was happening is that the nodejs version that comes pre-installed with the PI is an older version and needs to be upgraded in order to install this particular node for node red so I used:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This upgrades the nodejs version to version 6 from 0.10.29. 0.10.29 is in the standard Raspberry PI Jessie installation at the time of this writing. Then the installation of the node-red I2C works just fine.